# Mac OS X key gen without password, can I remove it?

Tags: macos, github, ssh-keys

I generated my key pair on a new computer that I'm setting up for my development environment. I am already using my id_rsa.pub key in several places and don't wish to change it. When generating the key, I entered a passphrase and confirmed it. I believe this means that I must enter the passphrase every time my key is used or accessed, such as during `ssh` into a server or doing a `git push` to GitHub. I forgot that I could have just hit the enter key and skipped entering a password during generation.

What I want to know is if I can remove the passphrase so that it is as if I had just used the enter key when I was generating it or so that I can use the same key pair without having to use a passphrase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed here:
http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/security/ssl/remove-passphrase-password-from-private-rsa-key

1. SSH into a host that has your public key: `ssh my_user@myhost`
2. At the password prompt, `openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new`
3. Enter old passphrase
4. Back up and replace private ssh key:

`cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.backup`

`rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

`cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

5. Set key permissions: `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
6. Test it by logging in to the remote again.